# Vue v-bind:style not updating with nested data changes

Tags: vue.js

The component's style doesn't update with the itemStyleMap[index] value chage:

```
<view
  class="item"
  v-for="(item, index) in itemList"
  :key="index"
  :style="itemStyleMap[index]"
/>
```

I also tried:

```
<view
  class="item"
  v-for="(item, index) in itemList"
  :key="index"
  :style="{
    background: itemStyleMap[index]['background'],
    display: itemStyleMap[index]['display'],
    zIndex: itemStyleMap[index]['zIndex'],
    transform: itemStyleMap[index]['transform'],
    transformOrigin: itemStyleMap[index]['transformOrigin'],
  }"
/>
```

The itemStyleMap in `data` is something like this:

```js
{
  1: {
    background: 'unset',
    display: 'none',
    zIndex: 'unset',
    transform: 'unset',
    transformOrigin: 'unset',
  },
  2: {
    background: 'unset',
    display: 'none',
    zIndex: 'unset',
    transform: 'unset',
    transformOrigin: 'unset',
  },
  3: {
    background: 'unset',
    display: 'none',
    zIndex: 'unset',
    transform: 'unset',
    transformOrigin: 'unset',
  },
}
```

A more simple demo can be find here: https://jsfiddle.net/wfx6dhy5/7/

Is there any other better way to control infinate amount of style sets like this?

Comment: Your fiddle change `this.spanStyle.colot` to `this.spanStyle.t.color` or try this https://jsfiddle.net/hfner5j0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is wrong in your project but I did something like this and it works.
check this out.

https://jsfiddle.net/softvini/c4j8ou9r/4/

```
    <div id="app">
       <div v-for="item of itemList" :key="item" :style="itemStyleMap[item]">
         {{item}}
       </div>
     </div>

  var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      itemList: [0, 1, 2],
      itemStyleMap: [{
          background: "purple",
          display: "block",
          zIndex: "unset",
          transform: "unset",
          transformOrigin: "unset",
        },
        {
          background: "red",
          display: "block",
          zIndex: "unset",
          transform: "unset",
          transformOrigin: "unset",
        },
        {
          background: "brown",
          display: "block",
          zIndex: "unset",
          transform: "unset",
          transformOrigin: "unset",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
})
```

Maybe you need to read more about reactivity. So you can read it here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Answer (score 1):

in your https://jsfiddle.net/wfx6dhy5/7/ data should be a function.

```
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return {
      spanStyle: {
        t:{
          fontSize: "36px",
          color: 'yellow',
          border: null
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeColors() {
        this.spanStyle.color = (this.spanStyle.t.color == 'red') ? 'blue' : 'red';
      
        this.spanStyl.border = (this.spanStyle.t.border == '3px solid blue') ? '3px solid red' : '3px solid blue';
    }
  }
});
```

Also, you missed .t in changeColors method. `this.spanStyle.color` should be `this.spanStyle.t.color` and `this.spanStyl.border` should be `this.spanStyl.t.border`